# python (django) database returned result (u'string')

Tags: python, database, django

I am trying to access another database (another application) in django, and make a query to get some data within my django project with the following:

```
cursor = connections['another_db'].cursor()
cursor.execute("query here to fetch data")
retVal = cursor.fetchone()
```

The `retVal` is a text-type value in amysql database. After it's returned, I try to concat it with another string:

```
newString = "%s: %s" % (retVal, anotherString)
logging.debug("newString: %s" % newString)
```

I got the following output:

```
DEBUG:root:newString value: (u'RetValString',): anotherStringValue
```

Is there any way to remove the `(u' .. ')` wrapper, so that only `RetValString: anotherStringValue` shows?

Answer (score 3):

Your return value is a single item sequence (a tuple), not a string. This is standard from the Python DB-API:

> .fetchone()
>
> ```
>         Fetch the next row of a query result set, returning a
>         single sequence, or None when no more data is
>         available. [6]
>
>         An Error (or subclass) exception is raised if the previous
>         call to .execute*() did not produce any result set or no
>         call was issued yet.
> ```

So the immediate fix would be:

```
newString = "%s: %s" % (retVal[0], anotherString)
```

But, its always better to check for any return values:

```
cursor = connections['another_db'].cursor()
cursor.execute("query here to fetch data")
retVal = cursor.fetchone()
if retVal:
   newString = "%s: %s" % (retVal[0], anotherString)
```

As a bonus, you should wrap it in a try/catch block since fetchone will raise and exception if there are any problems.

Answer (score 0):

The `u'` indicates that retVal is in fact unicode. (Try printing `type(retVal)` )So to answer your question you can convert it to a 'regular' string by calling `retVal = str(retVal)`

Comment: i did retVal = str(retVal), and then print it with 
logging.debug('retVal: %s' % retVal)

i still get: (u'retValString',) .. any idea?

Comment: See burhan's answer above as well - I failed to notice that retVal is inside a tuple. So the fix with my sample of code would be retVal=str(retVal[0]) - that is grab the first element in the tupple and cast that to a string. However you should read and understand burhan's explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If the text is for presentation to a user, you should probably do nothing with it. Converting it to a string (using str()) would only be beneficial if you were passing it to something (like subprocess.Popen) that required a string.